# How to enable tab guides in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Some IDEs I have used provided access to vertical guides indicating tab spacing. I can not seem to find it in Visual Studio 2010. Is this option even available?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know Visual Studio doesn't support indent guides, but luckily there is an extension on the visual studio gallery pages called [Indent Guides](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30)

It's free- you just need to download it, install it and restart visual studio. It has several customization options. There may be other solutions as well (as part of commercial suites probably).

Comment: Thanks again for your help. The others indicated the same link, but I accept your answer because you posted it first.

Answer (score 4):

I think the [Indent Guides](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30/) extension does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Install this extension: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30